# Unable to locate the default servlet for serving static content. Please set the 'defaultServletName' property explicitly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring boot project as standalone that was originally developed for WAR deployment in a tomcat and uses older spring boot versions. 
I was able to write my main class that starts the application and I can see that its doing all startup activities that is done by original application but that I am stuck at below error that is thrown towards the very end.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lo
>   cate the default servlet for serving static content. Please set the 'defaultServletName' property explicitly.
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>           at com.app.def.run.Application.main(Application.java:72) [classes!/:?]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [APP.jar:?]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [APP.jar:?]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [APP.jar:?]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [APP.jar:?]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate the default servlet for serving static content. Please set the 'defaultServletName' property explicitly.
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.setServletContext(DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ServletContextAwareProcessor.java:103) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
>           ... 21 more

A quick solution or workaround will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add static servlet entry in webmvc-config.xml of spring application.

Given link has reference on how to set default servlet to refer at path /.

https://github.com/heroku/java-spring-sample/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml

Comment: Using java class you can register default servlet like by overwriting WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  class's method

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable("myCustomDefaultServlet");
   }